# Async Nature inside a for loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using async library for executing an array in serial manner as follows

```
async.eachSeries(Object.keys(req.body),function(elem, callback){
});
```

Inside this sync i am calling the backend which is also async as follows:

```
async.eachSeries(Object.keys(req.body),function(elem, callback){
client.search(Query).then(function(Data){
//Some computation with result(data)
});
});
```

And finally i am ending the loop to do some computation as follows:

```
var bodyLength = Object.keys(req.body).length;
async.eachSeries(Object.keys(req.body),function(elem, callback){
   client.search(Query).then(function(Data){
   //Some computation with result(data)
    });
    if(--bodyLength === 0){
        callback(null, notMyLocData, myLocData);------->This line is executed before computation from backend
    }
}, function(err, notMyLocData, myLocData){
      console.log("notMyLocData");
      console.log(notMyLocData);
      console.log("myLocData");
      console.log(myLocData);
});
```

But actually what i am getting is, as backend call in async before getting result for backend the callback is executed.  How can i restrict or wait(not sleep) for the backend call to finish and executed the next code.Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put your `if` statement inside the callback passed to `then()` function.

Comment: @Rodrigo Medeiros thnaks. I tried for that also. But in callback i am receiving notMyLocData and myLocData as undefined.

Comment: I got it now: the `async.eachSeries()` callback just receives an `error` argument. So, it doesn't matter what you are passing to the local `callback`, it'll only consider the first argument. If you want to use `notMyLocData` and `myLocData` in the last callback, you should use `async.mapSeries()`.

Comment: async.mapSeries() is not looping for me. Can you please explain how can i modify in eachSeries to accomplish this.

Comment: @Rodrigo Medeiros  Is it possible to have my own function as callback. And execute it when loop finishes.

Comment: Let's see if I understand: you want to do something with all items in the `Object.keys(req.body)` array, but just need the result from the last one, is that it?

Comment: @ Rodrigo Medeiros no not like that. For each items in Object.keys(req.body) i have to query in backed and populate it to an array as object. Finally i have to intersect using 1 field in that array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73931/discussion-between-rodrigo-medeiros-and-subburaj).